# C string conversion

Tags: c, string, algorithm, integer

I have the following scenario where any input string will be converted into an integer.

```
Example: 
result = get_integer_from_string("100"); 
result == 100; // true
```

How can I write this function without using any libraries? I am able to do it by using libraries.

Comment: what do you need is convert string into integer without libraries? am i right

Comment: Just use the library. That's what it's for.

Comment: I would iterate through string, convert the ascii character to a number ( using ascii values of '0' to '9' ), then add it to a total ( multiplying by 10, 100, etc depending on position ).

Comment: Parse the string character by character. Preferably left to right

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these Steps:

1. Parse the input string.
2. Check if the character is a digit or not.
3. Use some logic to convert digit in character format to integer format.
4. Also, you can implement Exception in case, input is not integer string.

I cannot tell you the code, it would not help you in learning, try implementing code yourself, it is very easy!!

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the string, from the end to the start. Get each digit, and convert it to a decimal value. Multiply the first (in the backward loop) by `1` and store the result. Multiply the second by `10` and add to the result of the previous. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is very prone to error conditions, but should work if string is valid integer:

```
int str2int(const char* str) {
    int result = 0;
    char* p = str;
    for (;;) {
        char c = *p++;
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            break;
        result *= 10;
        result += c - '0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

It has behavior close to `atoi()` - stop processing on any non-digit, and return 0 for empty input.

Comment: cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int str2int(char*)':
Line 4: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value...got this error from codepad

Comment: fixed. also changed logic to stop processing on any non-digit, much like `atoi()`

Comment: check this out, seems not working...http://codepad.org/h00XnwoR

Comment: your parameter must be string `"100"`, not integer `100`

Comment: still no changes chk this http://codepad.org/caFHGpXJ

Comment: it is difficult to write C code that is going to be compiled by C++ compiler in warnings treated as errors mode. fixed.